# Click срабатывает только один раз

Tags: jquery, click

Клик срабатывает только один раз, уже выносил за `$(document).ready(function() {`, писал с `$('#btn').off('click').on('click',function(e){`, `delegate` и `live` проходят мимо

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/load.php',
    data: {
      'ok': 'ok'
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(res) {
      $('#res').html(res);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: попробуй $('body').on('click','#btn',function(){ ... } Если ты вешаешь ивент на элемент который в последствии перегенирится - то лучше вешать на боди, документ как я показал

Comment: @Mr.D1rk , не пашет, кнопка по сути статична и не изменяется

Comment: где в документе находятся `#btn` и `#res` по отношению друг к другу, и что такое `#btn`?

Comment: @Igor это кнопка, рядом, но без разницы, так как даже alert не срабатывает по второму клику

Comment: @Rufex Это был толстый намек на то, что надо добавить html  в вопрос.